# I'm looking for rEFit for PPC Mac

Tags: live-usb, refit

http://refit.sourceforge.net/

What is Mac PPC's version of rEFit?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to give us details on what you need rEFIt for and how this is related to Ubuntu?

Comment: I posted all that info in that link. It shows what refit is used for on intel macs and how it is related to ubuntu.

Comment: In that link it also says that Apple hardware can't boot Ubuntu from USB.

Comment: It says that it is not well supported. But without refit it is impossible on intel macs. My Mac however is ppc and refit will not work on ppc. I need something like refit that I can install with my Mac ppc.

Comment: So please edit your question and ask this to people that may know how to do it. Sth like: "how do I boot a Mac PPC with Ubuntu on USB stick" & give us as much detail as possible.

Comment: But I have already asked that question. In several other forums and have given up. Now I just want a kind of refit for ppc. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Long ago I posted here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10343/how-to-create-yaboot-partition-using-a-ppc-mac

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10246/how-to-make-usb-debian-squeeze-disk-for-ppc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPC Macs **can**<strike>'t</strike> boot from USB; you will need to know your way around OpenFirmware.

The only bootloader I have used for PPC ("New-World" Macs) is [yaboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaboot) and it seems to run from a USB stick. <strike>seems to require its own partition on a Linux-only system</strike>.

Edit: See the better answer elsewhere in this thread. That's a bit of work, though, and you still need to burn a CD to copy from.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article on how to boot Mac PPC from USB at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=780320.

This works, as I needed it to reboot my PPC Mac recently after replacing a failed HDD.

-jh

Answer (score 0):

i am running ubuntu 10.10 on my macbook 2,1 (intel core 2 duo). you can boot ubuntu from a usb stick on macs. that was how i installed my ubuntu. i can direct you to the mactel ubuntu community support page, however i have no knowedge of ppc or anything like that. i would recommend a liveCD as opposed to a usb stick though. much easier.

here is the site for mactel ubuntu stuff, somewhere in that list is a way to get ubuntu on a usb stick.i think there is also a set of instructions on the ubuntu main page.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages

EDIT: rEFIt is a bootloader for macs, this is required for 1) syncing partition tables and 2) GUI for booting (it really helps for starting up)

Comment: But refit only works with intel macs. That's why I posted this question looking for something that works with ppc macs but can do the same thing.

Comment: @Joshua i have an intel mac. i have no knowledge of PPC macs at all. i would recommend googling "Ubuntu on ppc macs" as stated above. i am trying to give you as much as i know. a quick google search comes up with this page, it looks promising (i skimmed it) http://bit.ly/gtOV8P
im trying to help, but once again, i know almost nothing about ppc macs. remember, google is your friend when dealing with things that are strange or unknown to you.